# Why no Kaddish DeRabbanan at Minchah?

Tags: tefilla, torah-study, kaddish, mincha-afternoon-prayer

Rambam writes in [Seder HaTefillah](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_The_Order_of_Prayer.2.33?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> קדיש דרבנן כל עשרה מישראל או יתר שעוסקין בתלמוד תורה שעל פה ואפילו במדרשות או בהגדות כשהן מסיימין אומר אחד מהן קדיש
>
> *Kaddish DeRabbanan*: Anytime ten or more Jews study *torah shebe'al peh*, even *midrashim* or *aggadah*, when they finish, one of them says *kaddish*.

This is indeed customarily performed whenever we study *torah shebe'al peh* during prayer, for example after *korbanot* before *shacharit*, *pitum haketoret* after *shacharit* on (weekdays and) *shabbat*, and *bameh madlikin* on Friday night.

See also [these](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/when-is-there-kaddish-after-a-shiur) [questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61443/why-would-someone-recite-kaddish-drabbanan-but-not-kaddish-yatom).

However, I have never seen this done at *minchah* in any *shul* I've been to that recites *korbanot* before *ashrei* (some *nusach sefard* and many *nusach edot hamizrach*). It also does not appear in any *siddur* I've ever seen. (See e.g. [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Sefard,_Weekday_Mincha,_Korbanot.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Edot_HaMizrach,_Weekday_Mincha,_Offerings.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).)

**Why does there not appear to be a custom to recite *kaddish derabbanan* after *pitum haketoret* for those who communally recite it as part of *korbanot* before *minchah*?**

(I'm aware that there are those who advocate only saying *kaddish derabbanan* after learning *aggadah* specifically. If that's the case, they could easily add a suitable passage (e.g. '*yehi ratzon ... sheyibaneh beit hamikdash...*') as we do after other passages of *torah shebe'al peh*, in order to recite the *kaddish*.)

Comment: The Kaddish after Korbanot and Pitum haKetoret, while based in this Halakha, really only caught on due to Kabbalistic concerns. They aren't present in old siddurim (even a hundred years ago they weren't ubiquitous). So your answer probably lies in Kabbalah though I haven't a clue what it is (perhaps it's related to Rama/MagenAvraham/ArukhHashulchan at the end of 234, and how that relates to the structure of the representations of the various kabbalistic worlds in Mincha)

Comment: In the Yerushalmi Edot haMizrach minyanim in Talpiot they always recite Kadish DeRabanan between Ptach Eliyahu and Korbanot. (I assume it's not unique to this location - And it's this way in my phone's siddur)

Comment: @DoubleAA Emden has it: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=166

Comment: @kazi he's not that old and was indeed influenced by Kabbalah. he says right there on that page that this kaddish is here to separate the olam asiya from yetzira or something like that, not because we just learnt torah so it's obligatory.

Comment: @DoubleAA It would be interesting to track the first occurrences in books. Indeed, I don't see KdR in early Italian machzorim there.

Comment: @DoubleAA Artscroll cites Rambam at this point in Shacharit in this vein, and since we do a bit of everything in Korbanot, it seemed logical to me. But this theory obviously fails to explain the lack of KdR at minchah.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Like I said this can be based in the real Halakha in the Rambam etc. about Kaddish after Torah study, but its application in prayer settings is largely Kabbalistic. They didn't used to say KdR in prayer settings pretty much ever, perhaps because they thought everyone reading Korbanot to themselves wasn't public study, perhaps bc people did Korbanot at home, perhaps bc the later Kaddish after Yishtabach/Alenu covered it, etc.

Comment: @DoubleAA Interestingly, Tur mentions [kaddish after ein kelokeinu](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur,_Orach_Chaim.133?lang=bi) and [after bameh madlikin](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur,_Orach_Chaim.270.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) but not, as far as I can see, after korbanot.

Comment: @JoelK IIRC the bach there (?) says nobody ever says KdR ever, and the arukh hashulchan there (just 100 years ago in ashkenaz!) says they didn't say kaddish between ein kelokeinu and alenu. fwiw remember also the tur is talking about learning bameh madlikin after maariv not before it, and the tur doesn't specify KdR; it could be he meant regular kaddish yatom. the mishna berura in his kuntres maamar kaddishin never mentions a KdR after ryishmael, only a kaddish yatom after mizmor shir.