# Kaddish deRabbanan during public prayers

Tags: minhag, shacharis-morning-prayer, kaddish, kabbalat-shabbat

As a follow-up of this [interesting question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91905/why-no-kaddish-derabbanan-at-minchah), I would like to take one step back. Most say *Kaddish deRabanan* after the morning *Korbanot* (see [Emden](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=166)), *Ein kEloheinu* and *Bameh Madlikin.* In contrast, Heidenheim seems to omit this kaddish at [all](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19723&st=&pgnum=28) [three](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19723&st=&pgnum=121) [places](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19723&st=&pgnum=159). What are the earliest sources that mention this practice in a public prayer setting?

Comment: [או בקדיש דרבנן שאומרים אחר במה מדליקין](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/ביאור_הלכה_על_אורח_חיים_קלב#סעיף_א)

Comment: [וכן מנהג כל ישראל אחר פרקים ואין כאלהינו ובמה מדליקין הגדת אר"א כו' א"כ כשלומדין משניות י"ל הגדה אחריו כדי לומר קדיש](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/מגן_אברהם_על_אורח_חיים_נד#סעיף_ג)

Comment: Note even after the earliest source it still might not have been widespread like you often see it today

Comment: @DoubleAA I just want to understand where this minhag comes from, and who advocated it. Based on the books, it seems that for western Ashkenazim it wasn't at all in practice.

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in a comment there, [Tur OC 270](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur,_Orach_Chaim.270.1?with=all&lang=bi) mentions a *kaddish* after *bameh madlikin* and [Tur OC 133](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur,_Orach_Chaim.133.1?with=all&lang=bi) in the name of Rav Amram Gaon mentions a *kaddish* after *ein kelokeinu*. (I would be extremely surprised if there is an earlier source than Rav Amram Gaon).

It should be noted (as was pointed out by @DoubleAA) that in both of these places, Tur only mentions *kaddish* generically, but does not talk specifically about *kaddish derabbanan*.

Comment: Indeed, that was the reason why I asked this question. In early Italian printed machzorim I couldn't find reference either.

Comment: Also look here, Emden omits _Amar R' Eleazar_ (with KdR) after _Ein kEloheinu_, and goes on with _Aleinu_ http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=343

Comment: I'm not sure the line about Kaddish is part of the quote from R Amram. Note also the Maharshal quoted in the Bach there that the Kaddish after Ein Kelokeinu was only for those communities that put it after Alenu and in his community there was no Kaddish after Ein Kelokeinu since they said Kaddish later after Alenu.