# Why K"Yatom and not K"Derobonnon?

Tags: tefilla, talmud-gemara, kaddish, motzei-shabbos

In my Artscroll Siddur Yitzchak Yair Hashalem, after the section called Vayiten L'cha there is a small piece of instruction:

בכמה קהילות אמרים כאן קדיש יתום

In some congregations [people] say here Mourner's Kaddish

But this section of prayer has in it both sections from Nach and from the Talmud. What determines that in this spot, one would say the Mourner's Kaddish and not the one Derobonnon which is said after reading a "non legal" section of the [Talmud](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1835997/jewish/What-Are-the-Different-Kaddish-Prayers.htm)?

Comment: Similar to perek at mincha see  machlokes in Kaf Hachaim.

Comment: Germans omit the section from [Megillah 31a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.31a.12?lang=bi) and many others don't consider such chapters being read during prayer learning in public.

Comment: @Kazibácsi do those who don't consider such chapters' being read as "learning" say K"D after the section of text after Ein Kelokeinu?

Comment: Nope they say mourners' kaddish there as well, just open a Rödelheim siddur. I don't know how much would you accept it as an answer, but I'm fairly convinced that this is the reason for the debate.

Comment: @rosends indeed not everyone says KD there. The Aruch Hashulchan writes that the common custom in Lithuania was to recite no Kaddish there and to go straight to Alenu.

Comment: See also my related question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91909/15256

Comment: @Double IIRC, this is how it is (was) done at R' Hamburger's schul (despite R' Heidenheim). But interestingly they did say ק"י after Bameh Madlikin.

Comment: @rosends those who don't say it there are seemingly saying a KY after Alenu on the Ein Kelokeinu stuff too

Comment: @Kazi I have a pet theory that the kaddish type is determined by the last section recited, so if you study agada and then switch to reciting tehillim you say KY.

Comment: @DoubleAA Assuming that you do say KdR after prayer-like agada?

Comment: @Kazi either way, the questions are unrelated